# try-catch in JavaScript : how to get stack trace or line number of the original error

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile

When using TRY-CATCH in JavaScript, how to get the line number of the line that caused the error?

On many browsers, the below code will work great and I will get the stack trace that points to the actual line that throw the exception.

However, some browsers do not have "e.stack". IPhone's safari is one example.

Is there someway to get the line number that will work for all browsers?

```
try
{
   // lots of code here
   var i = v.WillGenerateError; // how to get this line number in catch??
   // lots of code here
} 
catch (e) 
{
     alert (e.stack)  // this will work on chrome, FF. will no not work on safari 
     alert (e.line)  // this will work on safari but not on IPhone
}
```

Many thanks!

UPDATE: 
I found that e.line works on safari but still not available on IPhone, latest iOS version

Comment: Why not just remove the `try...catch` and look at what line the standard error message points to?

Comment: @robertc I need the try...catch for other reasons. For example, I would like to capture the state when the error occurred

Comment: Are you getting that on the iPhone at the moment?  You're looking for more information in order to track down an error, there is a way to get more information than you have at the moment, why do you not want to take advantage of it?

Comment: @robertc For example - I would like to capture caurrent values in all function variables exactly when the error occurred. As far as I know, i can only do this in catch.

I know that I can omit try ... catch all together, and use window.onerror to give me the line number but this is not enough AND it also is not available in all browsers

Comment: Then after you're found the line number, put the `catch` back...

Comment: @robertc he he, that is good for debugging assuming you can replicate the error. not so good when you are trying to capture information about an error that you do not know how to reproduce.

Either case, assume that i MUST have try...catch

Comment: Well if you're writing an error logging mechanism rather than simply debugging it probably would have helped to mention that in the question.

Comment: Try [stacktrace.js](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace), which was made exactly for that.

Comment: thank you but: "You can also pass in your own Error to get a stacktrace not in IE or Safari, though :("

Which is exactly my situation :)

Comment: Ah right, didn't see that :(

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `e.lineNumber`.
For example:

```
try {
   var i = v.WillGenerateError;
} catch (e) {
   alert(e.lineNumber);
}
```

Comment: @GregBala It's a [mozilla extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Comment: ah I see, well FF does support e.stack so that one is fine... just need safari to work ...

Comment: lineNumber  is not standard at all, only supported by FireFox see : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Error/lineNumber

Answer (score 3):

Full compatability with all browsers

```
var aux = err.stack.split("\n");
aux.splice(0, 2); //removing the line that we force to generate the error (var err = new Error();) from the message
aux = aux.join('\n"');
throw message + ' \n' + aux;
```

> Error: myError at :4:11 at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn
> (:777:140). at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:710:34). at
> Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:626:21).

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
   0();
} catch (e) {
   alert(e.line);
}
```

Using 'e.line' in a try…catch block will give the line number of the error in Mobile Safari.

Comment: Hi. I have zero expertise in this area, but your post came up in a review queue. Mainly because it's code-only, without any explanation. it's always a good idea to add some explanation of what you changed, and why it solves the problem. Don't forget that heaps of newbies (or people unfamiliar with your field of expertise) are on S/O and they can learn a thing or two from you... but only if you tell them :) What may be obvious to you isn't so much to them.

Comment: It's not code-only, I have a description afterwards.  To expand on it slightly: Using 'e.line' in a try…catch block will give the line number of the error in Mobile Safari.